# How to roughly estimate long term term premia?

Tags: fixed-income

Is there a way to crudely estimate term premia in long term bonds? I understand there is a well developed and widely available model from the NY Fed ([ACM Model](https://www.newyorkfed.org/research/data_indicators/term_premia.html)) but I'm wondering if there is a 'quick and dirty' method which can be applied to any curve, as I am trying to estimate the term premium in the long end of the Brazilian curve (e.g. 10y - 3m rates?)

Answer (score 2):

The ACM term premium can be replicated very well with a simple linear regression:

$$\text{10-Year ACM TP} = -1.84 - 0.0579\times\text{3M Rate} - 0.6922\times\text{2Y Yield} - 0.4329\times\text{5Y Yield} + 1.6159\times\text{10Y Yield}. $$

Adjusted $R^2$ of this regression is 0.96. You can perhaps apply these coefficients to Brazilian rates to get some crude estimate. How well will it work? Probably not very well, unless the Brazilian interest rate dynamics happen to be the same as the US, which seems highly unlikely.

Other easy ways to measure term premium is to look at forwards. For example, the difference between 7y forward 3m rate and 10 year forward 3m rate can be used as a proxy (that far out into the future, people are unlikely to have strong views about rate direction, so the slope of the curve mostly likely can be attributed to term premium, rather than changing rate expectations).

Comment: Interesting. If I plug in 3mo=1.0139, 2yr=1.3464,5yr=1.8136,10yr=2.253 I get a US ACM term premium of 0.0285. Only 2.8 basis points (but at least it is positive).

Comment: @noob2 Yeah, the precise values of term premia became meaningless to me a while ago (after obsessing over them for years...) I'm sympathetic to those who believe monetary policies have pushed term premium to deeply negative territories, but I personally don't buy it. These models are great theoretical exercises, but completely defy logic – no rational investor would buy an asset if they truly believe that the ex-ante risk premium is negative (they can, after all, freely choose to hold cash). For me, the low level of rates is a reflection of low future rate expectations, not negative premia.